# Including an assembly with your DotNetNuke Module?

Tags: dotnetnuke, assemblies, dotnetnuke-5

I'm developing a DotNetNuke Module using the [nonIIS method](http://adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/DNN4_DevelopmentEnvironment_noIIS/) of module development.  Is there any way to include a 3rd-party [assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly) in your module (when setting it up for deployment)?

I thought about adding it as a reference to the dotnetnuke_nonIIS website project as a whole, but that doesn't seem right considering it's a dependency of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your local development environment may look like, you will most likely want to be able to deploy the module to a DNN site on its own.

To do that, you can create an installable module zip package - which consists of all of your module assets and a manifest file describing them so that DNN may process them and perform the appropriate actions (run scripts, deploy assemblies to the bin) upon installation.

Check out the [DNN wiki](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/tabid/1409/loc/allpages/Cat/Packaging/Default.aspx) for more information about packaging.